# Integrating closed loop of implicit curve

Tags: integration

I’ve been trying to find the exact area of the closed loop of this implicit curve:

$$
\sin(\cos(xy)) = \cos(\sin(x))
$$

[image: Initial curve without any rearranging]

The loop exists between the lines $x = \arcsin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ and $x = \pi - \arcsin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$.

With some rearranging, this curve has the same closed loop:

$$
\cos(xy) = \frac{\pi}{2} - \sin(x)
$$

[image: New curve with same loop after rearranging]

I’ve tried attempting

$$
2\int^{ \pi - \arcsin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}_{\arcsin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)} \frac{\arccos\left( \frac{\pi}{2} - \sin(x)\right)}{x}\text{d}x
$$

which gives an approximate value of $\approx 2.02$ when done numerically (and multiplying by two because taking $\arccos$ gives only the positive part).

This integral looks very tricky and I’ve tried substituting $u = \sin(x)$ but this doesn’t work because the limits both come out the same.

I’ve also tried converting to polar form but haven’t been able to get this to come out nicely.

Is there any way of finding the area of this loop exactly, without having to resort to numerical methods? It feels like there’s no closed form but I am wondering if there’s another technique I could use here that would give a satisfying answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, but most integrands you can easily write out using elementary functions do not have nice closed-form anti-derivatives. Your best bet to get an exact value is to recast it somehow as the integral of an analytic function along a closed curve on the complex plane, and use the Residue theorem. But most likely you are going to have to live with the reality that all you can is come up with approximations (but come on, even all we know about the value of $\pi$ is a really good approximation).